# Why is はじめ written with the kanji 初 as opposed to 始 to convey "the beginning"?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

I frowned upon my textbook when I saw the word 初【はじ】め (the beginning) for the first time (no pun intended). The reason is that so far, I understood the idea of "start" is conveyed by 始, whereas the concept of "first" is conveyed by 初. Therefore, according to my experience, I would expect はじめ to be spelt 始め only.

For example:

**初**

> **初**めてのちゅう the **first** kiss
> **初**級 the **first** level
> 世界**初**の車 the **first** car in the world

**始**

> パーティーの開**始**に合わない not in time for the beginning of the party
> 授業を**始**めよう let's start the lesson

However, it turns out that both spellings exist depending on whether "the beginning" is in terms of time, or in terms of a process that someone starts, as explained in this excellent [answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57913/32952) by [Eiríkr Útlendi](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/5229/eir%c3%adkr-%c3%9atlendi) (thank you!).

My question is, **why** or **how** did 初 come to be used to convey this meaning of "beginning" in some instances such as はじめ, replacing 始?

よろしくお願いします！

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When it comes to any question about *"why is word XX spelled with kanji YY instead of kanji ZZ?"*, or *"what is the difference in nuance between kanji spelling AA and kanji spelling BB of the same word CC?"*, you're ultimately asking about the kanji themselves -- and this often means we want to look at those words in Chinese to uncover additional information.

For instance, if we examine the senses of [the Chinese term 初](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%88%9D#Chinese), we see the following definitions:

1. initial; inceptive
2. original; first; primary
3. elementary; basic
4. beginning; start
5. initially; originally

Meanwhile, [the Chinese term 始](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A7%8B#Chinese) has these definitions:

1. to begin; to start
2. beginning; start
3. initial; first
4. then; only then; only after

Turning our attention back to the Japanese terms that include these kanji, we see some of this Chinese background reflected in the modern Japanese meanings.  For instance, 初級 isn't just *the **first** level*, but more specifically *the **primary**, **elementary**, or **basic** level*, senses that we find with the 初 kanji but not with the 始 kanji.  Meanwhile, for 開始 is literally 開 ("to open; to start") + 始 ("to begin; first; then, only after").  One way of parsing this kanji spelling is *"things **open up** or **start up**, and **then** [other things happen]"*, a sense found with the 始 kanji but not the 初 one.  (Note that I'm stretching the point here -- in truth, 開始 was coined in Chinese, and could also be parsed as just "to open; to start" + "to start" as a kind of duplication of near-synonyms to reinforce the basic meaning.)

Looking at the alternative spellings of the *wago* or native-Japanese terms はじめ or はじめて, the Chinese-derived meanings of the Chinese-derived kanji still seem to have some relevance, where はじめ or はじめて spelled with 初 tends to have overtones like those above listed for 初, and where はじめ or はじめて spelled with 始 tends to have overtones like those listed above for 始.

---

Please comment if the above doesn't answer your question.

Comment: In the end, both kanji have overlapping meanings even in Chinese, hence the overlap in Japanese as well. Thanks for your thoughs on this!!