# What is the difference between 始めに and 初めに?

Tags: nuances, spelling, homophonic-kanji

I'd learned 始{はじ}めに to mean "in the beginning" or "firstly" a while back, and recently I came across 初{はじ}めに to have the exact same meaning.

I looked it up on the dictionary, and the two actually appear as alternative spellings for the exact same entry, as opposed to two separate entries with similar meanings.

Is there any nuance to when one should be used over the other; for instance, does the nuance with regards to starting something as it relates to time vs starting a process, as explained in the first part of [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57913/1330) apply here? Or are they completely interchangeable?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it is more or less interchangeable though there are differences strictly speaking.

As the linked answer says, 初 means the ordinal *first* and 始 means the beginning. Note other usages: 始める and not 初める for *to begin* (there is reading 初{そ}める); 初めて and not 始めて for *for the first time*.

はじめに is usually 初めに because it is *firstly* (esp. if it is followed by 次に etc.). But at the same time, you are beginning something when you say *firstly*, so 始めに is not completely wrong. In a sense, they are as interchangeable as *to begin with* and *firstly* are. The distinction is particularly vague for はじめ**に**. As mentioned above, using 始めて to mean *for the first time* is felt wrong more strongly.

Comment: So the connotation is 初める -> be the first of an anticipated sequence of events; 始める -> initiate a long-running event?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 初{そ}める is rarely used alone (in modern speech). It means *for the first time in the time period under discussion*.  A typical example is [書初]{かきぞ}め, which means the first calligraphic writing (required to do as homework in winter vacation) in the year. As a verb, it is rare even in combination - one that comes top of my head is [見初める](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%A6%8B%E5%88%9D%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B/#jn-212064).